# Solr curl ExtractOnly for Pdf file

Tags: curl, solr, apache-tika

I am working on solr, to index  all types of Document and extracting content from document without indexing using command line.

This below command i used to extract pdf file without indexing to solrCore , And this same command is working fine for  extracting 'Html and Xml' files but not working for pdf.

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?&extractOnly=true"  --data-binary @"E:/ApacheSolr/solr-6.5.1/example/exampledocs/solr-word.pdf"  -H 'Content-type:application/pdf'
```

Error :

org.apache.solr.common.SolrExceptionorg.apache.solr.common.SolrExceptionURLDecoder: Invalid digit (P) in escape (%) pattern400

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is that the whole URL, or did you remove something? (Since you have `?&` and not just `?`).

Comment: no, that is full URL only

Comment: Any reason why you're sending the document as `--data-binary`? This will send the content of the file as as the POST body. Try to use the `-F "myfile=@example/exampledocs/solr-word.pdf"` syntax instead.

Comment: I tried what u given above   *curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/corePomfret/update/extract?&extractOnly=true&wt=ruby&indent=true"  -F "myfile=@E:/ApacheSolr/solr-6.5.1/example/exampledocs/Client Trust Receipt.pdf*   , without contentType its retuning metadata and content

Comment: Above command working fine for normal text Pdf files. i want  content from image pdf file that content i am not fetch using above command.

Comment: is any TesseractOCR configuration i need to set in solr